# API Gateway with Beanstalk EC2 based Strapi v4 APIs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-api-gateway, strapi, amazon-vpc

I am using Strapi CMS v4 with ElasticBeanStalk, ECR and EC2 for api and web deployment. And I want the strapi apis to be exposed via API Gateway. We are using VPC with 1 public and 2 private subnets. Application Load Balancer(ALB) is in public subnet, EC2 is in private subnet1, DB is in private subnet2. Now EC2 is having strapi apis which are at private subnet1. For User Roles, we are using strapi role management instead of Cognito Identity/UserPools. We want to expose it's apis via API Gateway, please suggest.